# Oracle Procedure compile error with declared cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure and it's giving me "No errors" and then "ORA-24344 Success with compilation error"
If I run everything inside the procedure it executes correctly but when i try to create the package body it does not work. I narrowed it down to this one procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEG.SPCKG_AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_COMP IS

    TYPE OUT_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;    
    PROCEDURE CreateRptTables;

END;

GRANT EXECUTE ON TEG.SPCKG_AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_COMP TO TEG_USER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEG.SPCKG_AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_COMP IS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PROCEDURE CreateRptTables IS
    /*==========================================================================
    12/20/2013 TFS 24446 - Created function
    ==========================================================================*/
    DECLARE 
        CURSOR Cur_Comp IS 
            SELECT * FROM TEG.AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_COMP;  
    BEGIN 
        FOR compRow in Cur_Comp LOOP
            If (compRow.cis_bus_res_loop <> compRow.cis_bus_res_loop_c) Then
                --Insert information into the details table
                INSERT INTO TEG.AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_DET( Facility_id, Serv_Pipe_Num)
                VALUES(compRow.Facility_ID, compRow.Serv_Pipe_Num); 
            End If;
        END LOOP;
    END; 
END;

SHOW ERRORS
```

Comment: You are saying "show errors" shows nothing, but you get compilation errors?  Does not make sense.  Why are you not using a modern IDE (as opposed to SQLPLUS) for development?  Get oracle's sql developer.  it is free, and will be much more efficient at finding and editing errors.

Comment: It can make sense if you're creating objects in another schema I think; i.e. if you are not logged in as `TEG`. You can query `user_errors` or, in this case more like `all_errors`, to get the details.

Comment: Trust me, I wish i could use a more modern IDE but at a corporate business as a new guy that knows nothing about oracle, i dont have much say in what I have for software. I tried searching user_errors and it did not bring anything back. All_errors did the trick (It was the DECLARE keyword)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the "DECLARE" keyword.  That is only needed in an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 2):

You can query `user_errors` or `all_errors` to see the issue, if `show errors` doesn't show you anything for some reason.

An obvious problem in you procedure is that you have the `DECLARE` keyword. You only use that for anonymous blocks. Everything between the `PROCEDURE ... IS` and `BEGIN` is declaration in a named block.

Comment: Small correction. Not only in anonymous blocks declaration section is separated by the `declare` keyword, in triggers(named PL/SQL blocks) as well.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - yes, quite right. So is a trigger a named block? *8-)

Comment: `So is a trigger a named block?` Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use an explicit cursor? Simply do

```
INSERT INTO TEG.AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_DET( Facility_id, Serv_Pipe_Num)
SELECT Facility_ID, Serv_Pipe_Num
FROM TEG.AEC_CIS_SVC_PIPE_COMP
WHERE cis_bus_res_loop <> cis_bus_res_loop_c;
```

Comment: This code isnt complete, along with the bus_res_loop I have 43 other fields that i am comparing. I was just cutting out code to narrow down what the problem could be.